# the majority of whom are male or males

Tags: grammar, nouns, adjectives, grammatical-number, predicative-complements

Should I use singular or plural form of male here? I think it should be males. Am I correct?

> Social and cultural traditions often make it difficult for aid workers, the majority of whom are [*male/males*], to meet the women in the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words are correct. The first says that the aid workers are *male*, the second one says that they are *males* i.e. men. However, the second option sounds a bit odd for general speech.

Comment: Is it fair to say that in your answer the singular, _male_,  is an adjective, thus not having a plural form, and so correct, whilst the plural, _males_, is a noun, thus required to match the noun, _workers_, in number?

Comment: @Gypsy Spellweaver , that's one way to put it.